# Export to pdf in struts 1.x

Tags: java, struts, export-to-pdf

I have some values to be exported to PDF, how can i do this in struts?

I would like to do the following, have option button or link when the user clicks on the button or link than the user should get a download option to download the exported PDF file.

I have a resultset which needs to be exported to PDF.

Please help me how to go about.

Regards

Comment: Struts doesn't export to PDF. If you want to achieve it, you should use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or another PDF library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that may help you to do what you want:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

public class CreatePDF{
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:/data.pdf"));

        document.open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.addCell("Name");
        table.addCell("Address");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
                                        "root", "root");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from data");

        while(rs.next()) {
            table.addCell(rs.getString("name"));
            table.addCell(rs.getString("address"));
        }

        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

But before implementing it you have to put `itext.jar` into your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
And you also found plenty of methods to manipulate your pdf file.

Comment: upto this i also have done the same, but need to integrate with struts application, instead of creating the file in to specific location, i want to give the option for the user to download. I thinks some where we have to set `content-dispostion `i don't know where to and how to.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this example of an action class it may help you out.

```
       import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
       import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
       import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
       import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
       import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
       import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;
       import com.lowagie.text.*;
       import java.io.*;

        public class download extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

        /* forward name="success" path="" */
        private static final String SUCCESS = "success";


        @Override
        public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        Document document=new Document();
        System.out.println(clientIp);
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=temp.pdf");
        try
    {
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,out);
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello Pdf"));
            document.close();

    }
        finally
        {
          return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
        }
    }
```

Also update your struts-config.xml according to it.